# Primefaces, captcha and FacesMessage

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, captcha

I have integrated reCaptcha component in my JSF view (Primefaces) and I want to gather reCaptcha fails errors (blank or error values).

I have to use `<p:messages/>` component with `for` attribute because I have many `<p:messages/>` components (1 for tab in `<p:tabView/>` component) but when I define `id` attribute in my `<p:captcha/>` component and use that id in the `for` attribute of the `<p:messages/>`, it doesn't work. When I don't use `for` attribute to test, I see `FacesMessage` like :

> j_idt16:j_idt69 : bla bla bla...

but `j_idt16:j_idt69` id doesn't seem to exist in my generated HTML code...

If I use `for="j_idt16:j_idt69"` it doesn't work too...

So how can I dispatch `captcha` messages into proper `messages` component please ?

Comment: Please post an SSCCE containing the entire `<h:form>`.

Answer (score 1):

The Captcha provide by Primefaces didnt work for me. Please follow the following tutorial which solved my captcha problem using JSF 2 /Primefaces.

http://techzone4all.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/integrate-simple-captcha-to-web-project/

Comment: hi, thank you for this link. I succeed with my captcha but (I don't know how or why), it's checked BEFORE all others fields in validation. If its value is wrong, other fields are not validated. Weird behaviour but I don't care, it do the job...Ty

Comment: You're not answering the question without the need to click off the site to a different domain which is not guaranteed to be available in the future, hereby making your "answer" potentially worthless whenever the resource becomes unavailable. Please put the relevant information in the answer so that it's useful without the need to click off the site.

Answer (score 0):

To address your specific need, you should define values for the `validatorMessage`,`converterMessage` and `requiredMessage` attributes on the `<p:captcha/>`, to be able to display user-friendly messages for their respective situations. FYI the `<p:captcha/>` component is processed during the submit of it's enclosing form, i.e it cannot be attached to a specific component or anything like that.

For clean message display, you should only place the captcha component in a `<h:form/>` along with other  components relevant to the reCaptcha operation.

Comment: The `<p:messages>` is only global when `globalOnly="true"` is set.